# Defining an array of object with accurate types

Tags: typescript

New to Typescript, I have a quick question about typings an array of object.
Right now if I do :

```
const my_array = [{
    foo: "hello",
    bar: "Typescript"
  },
  {
    foo: "goodbye",
    bar: "JavaScript"
  }
];
```

It will by default infer my_array with a type of

```
{foo:string; bar:string;}[]
```

**My request :** I would like to have typings more accurate such as:

```
{foo: "hello" | "goodbye"; bar: // value according to foo }
```

I also would like to have a **DRY** solution and define my `foo` and `bar` values only once for better maintainability

Comment: When you say "value according to foo" I assume if `foo` is "hello" then `bar` is of a type, but if `foo` is "goodbye", then `bar` is of another type. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. In this case if foo is type "hello", then bar should be a type of "Typescript"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coaxing the compiler into inferring literal types for values is tricky when those values are contained as array elements or object properties.  Here is one possible way to go about it:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | object | {} | null | undefined | void;
const tupleOfNarrowObjects = 
  <V extends Narrowable, O extends { [k: string]: V }, T extends O[]>(...t: T) => t;
const my_array = tupleOfNarrowObjects(
  {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: "Typescript"
  }, {
    foo: "goodbye",
    bar: "JavaScript"
  }
);
```

If you do that, `my_array` will now be inferred as the following type:

```
const my_array: [{
    foo: "hello";
    bar: "Typescript";
}, {
    foo: "goodbye";
    bar: "JavaScript";
}]
```

which is as narrow as it gets: a tuple of objects whose values are string literals.  So the compiler knows that `my_array[0].foo` is `"hello"`.  And if you iterate over `my_array` the compiler will treat each element as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

How it works:

- The `Narrowable` type is essentially the same as `unknown`, except it is seen by the compiler as a union containing `string` and `number`.  If you have a generic type parameter `V extends N` where the constraint `N` is `string` or `number` or a union containing them, then `V` will be inferred as a literal type if it can be.
- Usually, when a type parameter `O` is inferred to be an object type, it does not narrow the property types to literals.  However, when `O` is constrained to an index-signature type whose value type is narrowable to a literal, like `{ [k: string]: V }`, then it will.
- Finally, when using a rest parameter of generic type constrained to an array type, the compiler will infer a tuple type for that parameter if possible.

Putting all that together, the above `tupleOfNarrowObjects` infers its argument as a tuple of objects of literal properties if possible.  It is ugly (three type parameters for a single argument) but it works: you don't have to repeat yourself.

Hope that helps you.  Good luck.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the answer and the good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can define types for each type of record:

```
type Alpha = {"foo": "alpha", "bar": number}
type Beta = {"foo": "beta", "bar": string}
```

Then you can define an array which is a list of either `Alpha`s or `Beta`s (called a union type)

```
let arr: (Alpha | Beta)[] = some_array();
```

When iterating over the array, TypeScript will know the types of the fields as

```
for (let el of arr) {
    // el.foo is "alpha" | "beta"
    // el.bar is number | string
```

But if you check the `.foo` tag, TypeScript will narrow the type of `.bar`, because it actually knows each element is either a `Alpha` or `Beta`:

```
    if (el.foo == "alpha") {
        // el.bar is number
    } else {
        // el.bar is string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current Typescript implementation from version 3.7.5, provides limited support for deducing compile-time constant narrow argument types, but specific construction allows it:

```
type Narrowable = "" | 0 | true | false | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {} | [Narrowable] | { [k in keyof any]: Narrowable }

function gen<T extends Narrowable>(x: T): T { return x };

const f = gen(["www", 1,2,3,[1,2,3,[5,"qqq"],"str"],4, {a:5,b:{c:{a:54,b:"www"}}}])
```